# what is the algorithm behind the factor command in linux?

Tags: linux, algorithm, command, prime-factoring, factorization

**The `factor` command prints the prime factors of specified integer NUMBER.**

When I tried it

```
factor 12345678912345678912
```

even for such big numbers, it results within milliseconds.

**Which algorithm is it using?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gnu coreutils manual informs that [Pollard's rho algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) is being used.

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/factor-invocation.html

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of one version of the source for GNU factor:

http://www.futuretg.com/FTHumanEvolutionCourse/Source/factor.c

It includes routines for both trial division and Pollard's rho. Looks to me on a quick scan as if it uses trial division to find some small factors (up to about `lg(n)^2`, which is about 4000 in this case), then Pollard if what's left isn't probably-prime. In this case that's `205432623008947` if I'm right about the 4000, i.e. `35129 * 5847949643` .

The second-largest prime factor in your example is `35129`, and the square root of the largest is around `76471`. So trial division alone would be fast, since it only has to try about 25 thousand candidates.

Answer (score 1):

From the [source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/factor.c#L38):

> Algorithm:
>
> 1. Perform trial division using a small primes table, but without hardware
>    division since the primes table store inverses modulo the word base.
>    (The GMP variant of this code doesn't make use of the precomputed
>    inverses, but instead relies on GMP for fast divisibility testing.)
> 2. Check the nature of any non-factored part using Miller-Rabin for
>    detecting composites, and Lucas for detecting primes.
> 3. Factor any remaining composite part using the Pollard-Brent rho
>    algorithm or if USE_SQUFOF is defined to 1, try that first.
>    Status of found factors are checked again using Miller-Rabin and Lucas.
>
> We prefer using Hensel norm in the divisions, not the more familiar
> Euclidian norm, since the former leads to much faster code.  In the
> Pollard-Brent rho code and the prime testing code, we use Montgomery's
> trick of multiplying all n-residues by the word base, allowing cheap Hensel
> reductions mod n.
>
> The GMP code uses an algorithm that can be considerably slower;
> for example, on a circa-2017 Intel Xeon Silver 4116, factoring
> 2^{127}-3 takes about 50 ms with the two-word algorithm but would
> take about 750 ms with the GMP code.

In general, `factor` is pleasingly fast.  However, it isn't magic; if you pick pathologically difficult numbers to factorize, it slows down dramatically.

The underlying security of [RSA encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) is based on the difficulty of factorizing 2 large co-primes.  So let's see how hard we can push `factor` with large coprimes.  The largest number `factor` is able to factorize is 2<sup>127</sup>-1 (presumably represented internally with an int64_t), which happens to be prime:

```
$ factor $(bc <<< 2^127)
factor: ‘170141183460469231731687303715884105728’ is too large
$ factor $(bc <<< 2^127-1)
170141183460469231731687303715884105727: 170141183460469231731687303715884105727
$ factor $(bc <<< 2^127-2)
170141183460469231731687303715884105726: 2 3 3 3 7 7 19 43 73 127 337 5419 92737 649657 77158673929
$
```

Both 2<sup>127</sup>-1 and 2<sup>127</sup>-2 factorize almost immediately; 2<sup>127</sup>-1 is quickly found to be prime, and 2<sup>127</sup>-2 has relatively small factors.

What about something harder?  The product of 2 factors of the order of 2<sup>60</sup> will be approaching the higher order of what factor can work on.  So how about the next 2 primes above 2<sup>60</sup>?

```
$ primes $(bc <<< 2^60) | head -2
1152921504606847009
1152921504606847067
$ bc <<< 1152921504606847009*1152921504606847067
1329227995784916015866073631529372603
$ time factor 1329227995784916015866073631529372603
1329227995784916015866073631529372603: 1152921504606847009 1152921504606847067

real    0m30.628s
user    0m30.578s
sys 0m0.004s
$
```

So as the number of bits of coprime factors increases, factorization time increases much more rapidly.